# Is ormer another name for abalone, or is it a related animal?

Tags: shellfish

I've seen a recipe for ormer that requires it to be beaten a lot before stewing for a long time, and I've seen abalone recipes that are quick and easy.

Answer (score 2):

A quick search on google indicates that ormer is in the same grouping as abalone and sea snails, and is indeed a type of abalone.

Comment: I'd no idea that so many different creatures could be called abalone, or ormer for that matter.

Comment: Why would the type called ormer need such extreme treatment before eating it?

Comment: Any species of abalone needs a fair amount of tenderizing, as I understand it.

Comment: I'd come across a recipe for Channel Islands ormer casserole that called for the ormer to be well-beaten, and then I'd seen recipes for abalones that use the meat right away without (instructions for) tenderising.  With abalone being the more popular I would expect then that it goes without them saying that you'd need to prepare the abalone before proceeding with the recipe.

Comment: here's a link to the recipe if it's of interest http://guernseydonkey.com/?p=12119